# External Html and JS for components?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am new at Vue js and I have one question.
can I split a component into Html and js and then use it in other Html files and components? if so how can I do that? otherwise, my index.html will be quite long.
I want to have this structure:

[image]

And want to use everything in my **index.html**. And I want something like tileBody and the verticalTile component.

index.html

```
<html>
  *head*
     <body>
      <div id="app">
         <verticalTile></verticalTile>
      </div>
     </>
</html>
```

verticalTile.html

```
<vertical-tile>
   <tileBody></tileBody>
</verticalTile>
```

tileBody.html

```
<tileBody>
  <tileInfo></tileInfo>
</tileBody>
```

thank you for every help

Answer (score 1):

This is going to appear as unhelpful but ultimately you need to learn how VueJS works. Stackoverflow isn't here to teach you the basics of a framework.

Below are a few helpful videos for VueJS beginners. They cover the problems you're having.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrxBCBibVo0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXpIoQ_rT_c

---

EDIT: So to elaborate on our comment thread, you can separate files out like this. Importantly, call your logic file something different to your template file so you don't accidentally import that and not the template.

**Your file structure would look something like ...**

```
└ /components
  └ /BarcodeLookup
    └ BarcodeLookup.css
    └ BarcodeLookupLogic.js
    └ BarcodeLookup.vue
```

**Your Vue file ...**

```
<style scoped src="@/components/BarcodeLookup/BarcodeLookup.css"></style>
<script src="@/components/BarcodeLookup/BarcodeLookupLogic.js"></script>

<template>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

**Your JS file ...**

```
export default {
    name: 'BarcodeLookup',
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    methods: {
        lookupBarcode() {}
    }
};
```

Your CSS file ...

```
.some-class {
    background: whitesmoke;
}
```

Importing the component works exactly the same.

Comment: i only want to find an clearer way without having one file with thousand lines of code. it should be easier to read and not confusing. i know the basics bu t i think this is not a basic thing

Comment: This genuinely is a fundamental basic of how VueJS is built. I design and build enterprise level VueJS apps. You need to understand VueJS basics and whether you want to use compiled vs. runtime vs. serverside rendered and how each one works.

Comment: i know how vuejs works and i use x-templates at this moment but my  idex.html is too big now and confusing

Comment: @lenjah I've edited my original response to provide further insight. Again, this is pretty basic stuff. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your requirements though ...